# Visual C++ saying void function needs to return a value

Tags: c++, function, void

Visual C++ is saying my void function needs a return value

I compiled this on my mac, and it worked perfectly, but now I am trying to compile this with Visual c++ (using windows 7)

Heres the build log:

> Command Lines Creating temporary file
>   "c:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\Projects\magicsquare\Debug\RSP00000822923000.rsp"
>   with contents [ /Od /D "WIN32" /D
>   "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE"
>   /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd
>   /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc90.pdb" /W3
>   /c /ZI /TP ".\magicsquare.cpp" ]
>   Creating command line "cl.exe
>   @"c:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\Projects\magicsquare\Debug\RSP00000822923000.rsp"
>   /nologo /errorReport:prompt"
>
> Output Window Compiling...
>   magicsquare.cpp
>   c:\users\jonathan\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2008\projects\magicsquare\magicsquare.cpp(224)
>   : error C4716: 'check' : must return a
>   value
>
> Results Build log was saved at
>   "file://c:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\Projects\magicsquare\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
>   magicsquare - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

my function header and function

```
void **check (int **, int);

void **check(int **matrix, int size)
{   
    //check if first row and last row are the same
    int rsum = 0, rsum2 = 0;
    bool rowflag = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        rsum += *(*(matrix + 0) +i);
        rsum2 += *(*(matrix + size - 1) +i);
    }

    //check if first column and last column are the same    
    int csum = 0, csum2= 0;
    bool columnflag = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
            csum += *(*(matrix + i) + 0);
            csum2 += *(*(matrix + i) + size - 1);
    }   

    //check if diagonals are the same
    int diagonal = 0, diagonal2 = 0;
    bool diagonalflag = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        diagonal += *(*(matrix + i) + i);

    int m = 0;
    int n = size - 1;   
    while (m <= size - 1)
    {
        diagonal2 += *(*(matrix + m) + n);
        m++;
        n--;
    }

    //if row, column, diagonal are the same
    if (rsum == rsum2 && rsum2 == csum && csum == csum2 && csum2 == diagonal && diagonal == diagonal2)
        cout << "This is a Magic Square\n" << endl;
    else 
        cout << "This is not a Magic Square\n" << endl;
}
```

heres the entire code if needed
http://pastie.org/691402

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your function is returning a (void **) which is a pointer to a void pointer. To make a void function simply declare it as:

```
void check(int** matrix, int size);
```

Your original code will compile with a warning in C but not in C++. Try this in Visual Studio 2008. Rename your file extension to .c instead of .cpp to force C compilation instead of C++ compilation. It will compile with a warning. But beware, if you ever used the return value of check, it would be garbage.

This link has more details:
http://pdhut.50megs.com/vczone/articles/diffc/diffc.htm

Comment: That's another question: "I have a function that should return a ptr. It doesn't and my compiler doesn't complain. Why?"

Comment: @Raptrex: Neither C nor C++ compilers are required to detect missing `return` statements. Missing return is not an error in C/C++. (BTW, the above answer is incorrect to claim that it will not compile in C++). Which means that this is a Quality-of-Implemetation issue. Some compiler go that extra mile to detect missing returns, some don't. You Mac compiler is apparently of a lazy variety, so it didn't detect it. Also, it is possible that your Mac compiler has a switch that forces it to detect this kind of problem, you just forgot to turn it on.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a `void` function, it's a `void **` function. That means you're required to return a pointer to a `void` pointer.

Answer (score 2):

That function is not void, is void**. Meaning it must return a pointer to a void pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Like everybody else pointed out, your return type is incorrect.  You're not returning anything in your function, so just remove the ** and you'll be good to go.

Out of curiosity, did you get any warnings when compiling on your mac?  g++ (on my Linux box) only gives a warning with -Wall.

Comment: See my annotation to one other answer: G++ 4.0.1 on MacOS X 10.5.8 only gives a warning with '-Wall'.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: same thing I noticed on Linux (g++ 4.3.4)

Answer (score 2):

Take out the ** on the return. i.e. the signature should be:

```
void check(int **matrix, int size);
```

Looking at your pastie.org code sample, my guess is that you copied and pasted the other functions but forgot to remove the **.